# Event triggered when selecting a ListBox item

Tags: python, events, listbox, wxpython, wxwidgets

I initialize a `wx.ListBox` like this :

```
mylistbox = wx.ListBox(self, style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
mylistbox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnEventListBox)
# some other things (append some items to the list)
mylistbox.SetSelection(5)
```

I also have :

```
def OnEventListBox(self, event):
    print 'hello'
    # plus lots of other things
```

**How to make that the command `mylistbox.SetSelection(5)` in the initialization is immediately followed by the call of `OnEventListBox`?**

*Remark* : It seems that `SetSelection()` doesn't generate a wx.EVT_LISTBOX automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html#a65fd7fd5e3b8e7451b225b581ead70b1):

> Note that [`SetSelection`] does not cause any command events to be emitted...

This is on purpose, so that the events don't all trigger while you're trying to set up the UI. You could just manually call `OnEventListBox` for the desired functionality.

Better yet, if you don't need the event for what you're doing on init, you could extract the initialisation into a separate function, then call that on init *and* in `OnEventListBox`.

Comment: Of course I could manually call myself `OnEventListBox` but with which `event` parameter? I cannot create myself an `event` because I don't really click on the listbox...

Or, another solution, I could create another function that is nearly a copy/paste of `OnEventListBox`, just for the purpose of initialization.

This is not very beautiful, that's why I asked if there was another solution...

Comment: If you don't need the event for what you're doing, you could extract the initialisation into a separate function, then call *that* on init and in `OnEventListBox`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe comment above is the right answer, I'd encourage you to edit your original answer to mention that this is the correct approach to execute some code for both the changes done by the user and by the program itself.